# Enums in headers, classes, and main

Tags: c++, enums

I'm confused as to where I can define an enum and where I can use it. I have 3 files, a main.cpp, function.cpp, and function.h (names have been simplified). In function.h I have

```
class Function{
  public:
    enum Letters{A, B, C};
//more stuff not related
  private:
//stuff
}
```

And function.h is #included in main.cpp and function.cpp

However in main.cpp I want to have a variable: Letters letter; so I can get an input from the user, set that input to type i.e letter = A, then use it for a constructor Construct construct(..., letter,...) because the constructor in function.cpp needs a "Letters" in the argument.

So is there any way to have access to the type "Letters" in main.cpp? If not I'm thinking about rewriting the constructor so that it takes in "string letterIn" argument then changes the string to Type i.e if(letterIn == "A") Type type = A;

(I generalized a lot of variable names here so it can apply for other people's situations, I can do into more detail about my own project if it will help)

Comment: Is `Letters` also private in your real code?

Comment: If you declare it public, you can use it as `Function::A`, `Function::B` and `Function::C` from your main. It was the main way to give an enum a scope before C++11.

Comment: Sorry I skimped out too much on the function.h example. I updated it now. My enum is under public. @Medinoc do you mean I can do Function::Letters letter;? I'm not following exactly, sorry I've never done enums before. edit: I just saw you answered this question on one of the comments on the question below. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to use the enum in a constructor, I assume you can make it public. It so, you can access it like:

```
class Function{
    enum Letters{A, B, C};
//more stuff not related
}

int main(int argc, char** argv} {

    Function::Letters letter1 = Function::A;
    //or
    Function::Letters letter2 = Function::Letters::A;

}
```

or, as [Medinoc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1455631/medinoc) pointed out, if you declare your enum as `enum class`

```
int main(int argc, char** argv} {

    Function::Letters letter = Function::Letters::A;
}
```

Comment: If it's an `enum` and not an `enum class` (C++11), it should be `Function::A` instead of `Function::Letters::A`.

Comment: it is enum, not enum class. So just to make sure I'm understanding this: I can do Function::Letters letter and then later letter = Function::A(B or C)?

Comment: @TommyK that's right, as long as the enum is public inside the Function class. You can do letter = Function::Letters::A as well.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN do it in many ways.

You can declare it inside the header that declares your class:

```
 class HasEnums
 {
    public:
       enum Letters { A, B, C };
    ...
    HasEnums(Letters letter) { ... }
 };
```

then in main.cpp:

```
#include "hasenums.h"

HasENums::Letters letter = A;

HasEnums h(letter);
HasEnums i(HasENums::B);
```

or in a header file, outside the class:

```
enum Letters { A, B, C };

class NoEnums
{
   public:
     NoEmums(Letters letter) { ... }
};
```

and then in main:

```
#include "noenums.h"

Letters letter = A;

NoEnums n(letter);
NoEnums m(B);
```

There are dozens of other possible scenarios, but these two seem the most reasonable, depending on what you actually want to describe. The benefit of having `Letters` declared inside the class is that you can have another `enum Letters` in another class, and use both without needing one renamed when you need noenums.h and the new file noenums2.h in the same compile unit.

Note also that you can make a private `enum`, which can't be used outside of the class:

```
class HasPrivEnum
{
   enum Letters { A, B, C };
   ...
  public:
   HasPrivEnum(Letters letter) {...}
};
```

but now you won't be able to compile code that uses `HasPrivEnum::Letters` outside of the class (without `friend` declaration). This can be useful in some cases, but not from what you describe.